# Formatting a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I got a dataframe looking like this:

```
       A    B    C 
0      1    2    3
1      2    2    1
```

I want to send the values from the dataframe into a HTTP POST where the format looks like this:

```
"1,2,3",
"2,2,1",
```

How is it possible to format the output from the dataframe to be able to achieve desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert values to strings if need join them:

```
L = df.astype(str).agg(','.join, 1).tolist()
print (L)
['1,2,3', '2,2,1']
```

For `json` output convert list:

```
import json

j = json.dumps(L)
print (j)
["1,2,3", "2,2,1"]
```

Comment: Thank you jazrael! It looks like this is performed column-wise instead of row-wise. How do I adjust it?

Comment: @OldSport - change `.agg(','.join)` to `.agg(','.join, 1)`